# wrong path for the categories in Octopress

Tags: octopress

I am trying to escaladate a problem with Octopress.
By analysing my blog with a SEO tool, I note that a "/" is missing (between blog and categories):

```
http://www.myblog.com/blogcategories/linux
```

I also note that, in the octopress/public/categories folder, for each category of my blog, one folder is created with one index.html file, i.e:

```
octopress/public/categories/linux/index.html
```

On the 22rd line, I see:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myblog.com/blogcategories/linux">
```

which is the source of my problem.
I would like to know which module in Octopress generates this file and what could be my mistake ?
I declared in _config.yml the following parameter:

```
category_dir: categories
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this completely solves your problem, but I found this site with lots of octopress hacks. There is a section about categories in the sidebar: http://www.narga.net/improve-octopress-advanced-tweaks-tips/

**Sidebar category list**
This plugin provides the category list and post count shown in the sidebar.

- Save `tag_cloud.rb` to `plugins/tag_cloud.rb`.
- Save `category_list.html` to `source/_includes/custom/asides/category_list.html`.
- Append to `default_asides` in `_config.yml`:
- Add to `_config.yml`: `default_asides: [asides/recent_posts.html, asides/github.html, asides/twitter.html, asides/delicious.html, asides/pinboard.html, asides/googleplus.html, custom/asides/category_list.html]`